# MVC and command line application

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, command-line, interface, command-line-interface

I'm having problems with using the MVC pattern in a command line application. 
Are there some good and/or simple c/c++ examples which i could study.

Comment: If you actually provided some hints as to what you're modeling someone might be able to come up with something for you.  As it is, you're kind of screwed.  While upriser is completely wrong about MVC only being for GUI and Web, he/she is right about the unlikelihood of finding an example.

Answer (score 0):

[javax.scripting](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/scripting/) intended usage would be a good example of abstract MVC, a script being in the user's role when relating to GUI-based MVC implementations